# Can't use lightdm-webkit-greeter

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, webkit

I'm trying to use `lightdm-webkit-greeter` instead of the default `unity-greeter` on Ubuntu 13.04.

First I installed the greeter:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm-webkit-greeter
```

Then I ran this command to change the greeter:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --greeter lightdm-webkit-greeter
```

Then I tested the greeter:

```
lightdm --test-mode
```

All I see is a black screen, although I can move my mouse. I've rebooted to test this as well, and it's the same result. Other greeters, such as `lightdm-gtk-greeter` and `lightdm-kde-greeter` work fine.

Why isn't `lightdm-webkit-greeter` working?

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the `greeter-session` option in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to the desired greeter.

Open up `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with any editor as root. For example `sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` then change the line

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

to

```
greeter-session=lightdm-webkit-greeter
```

If the file does not exist, let it contain

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=lightdm-webkit-greeter
```

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me: yesterday I was enjoying my perfect self-made theme on Xubuntu 12.04, but today I decided to install Ubuntu 13.04 and it started not to work.
As you may have already found out in the meanwhile, this is apparently a "lightdm-webkit-greeter" issue only affecting new kernels, or similar stuff:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm-webkit-greeter/+bug/1154065